# If I prove that $|A| > |\mathbb{N}|$, does it mean that $A$ is uncountably infinite?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

My intuition is that if something is larger than $\mathbb{N}$ then it follows that it is larger than $\mathbb{Q}$ as there is a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$. So if a set is larger than $\mathbb{Q}$, which is the boundary before going into $\mathbb{R}$, then it must be uncountably infinite.

But I am not sure if this is valid.

Comment: Read this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis) entry.

Comment: A very guarded yes.  If the cardinality of a set is greater than the cardinality of N it is uncoubtable.  But when one says a set is "larger" has one actually correctly shown it has a larger cardinality?  A depressingly common error is to say something like "ever natural number is an integer but negative integers are not natural numbers so there are more integers than natural numbers".  That is, of course WRONG. However there are more infinite sequences of 0s and 1s than there are integers, *IS* correct and those sequences *are* uncountable.

Comment: How is $\mathbb Q$ the boundary before going to $\mathbb R$? Surely $\mathbb Q \cup \{\sqrt{2}\}$ is countable - and so are the algebraic numbers. And how can you rule out a set of intermediate cardinality without the continuum hypothesis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if $|A| > |\mathbb N|$, then $A$ is uncountable (and infinite).  [This is *not* the Cointinuum Hypothesis. ]

On the other hand, you wrote $|A| > \mathbb N$.  What does that mean?  Do you mean $|A| > k$ for all $k \in \mathbb N$?  In that case, it does not follow that $A$ is uncountable.  For example $A = \mathbb N$ satisfies this.

Another warning.  $|A| > |\mathbb N|$ means: there is an injective map $\mathbb N \to A$, but there is no injective map $A \to \mathbb N$.  It is not enough to show there is a map $\mathbb N \to A$ that is injective but not surjective.  That would only show $|A| \ge |\mathbb N|$

Comment: This is my fault, I did not wrap the modulus around $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Does the cointinuum hypothesis state there is no coin whose value lies between $\aleph_0$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$?

Comment: Naturally I wrote that on purpose, to see if anyone was paying attention...

Answer (score 3):

Your set is infinite, because there is an injection $\mathbb{N}\to A$; it is not countably infinite, because this would mean $|A|=|\mathbb{N}|$.

Mentioning $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

If you have proven that its cardinality is greater than $\omega$, then you have indeed proven that the set $A$ is uncountable.

However, note that this does not mean the cardinality of $A$ is equal to the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$. We do not know if there are any sets whose cardinality is between that of the integers and the continuum.

Comment: I thought it was proven that both answers to CH were consistent iff ZFC was consistent? So isn't saying "we do not know" kind of misleading?

Comment: It was proven that CH is unprovable from ZFC. This does not tell us anything about the truth of CH.

Comment: Right, I was just commenting that your wording seems to imply that there hasn't been any result on the subject ("We don't know", but there *could* be)